# Do I need to replace my toilet's fill valve if it sounds like it's leaking air?

Tags: plumbing

My toilet fill valve sounds like it's leaking air - it’s mildly whistling. Does that mean it needs to be replaced?

Answer (score 2):

If it's working and re-filling the bowl and just making noise, it's probably just a bit of vibration in the water flow.  I have no idea how it could be "leaking air".  If it worries you or bothers you, toilet "guts" are not very expensive at all and easy to replace by a homeowner. Probably about $20 at a big box store.

Answer (score 2):

I took mine apart and cleaned it.  Whistle gone.......for 3 days, then came back.   I learned my lesson.

Replace it and save yourself the aggravation. They aren't that expensive. Way cheaper than my time screwing with it twice.